# Swift AutoDiff: How do we make a struct have a member variable that is a differentiable function of more than one parameter?

Tags: swift, swift5, autodiff

I would like to have the following:

```swift
import _Differentiation

struct S {
    var f: @differentiable(reverse) (Double, Double) -> Double
}
```

but the compiler complains `Error: Abort trap: 6` and the start of the stack trace is

```
Assertion failed: (isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"), function cast, file Casting.h, line 269.
```

If the member variable is a function of one parameter, the program builds:

```swift
import _Differentiation

struct S {
    var f: @differentiable(reverse) (Double) -> Double
}
```

but two or more parameters is not allowed.

We can write a function that has a differentiable function of two parameters as a parameter:

```swift
import _Differentiation

func g(f: @differentiable(reverse) (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    // function body
}
```

If a function can have this type of parameter, why can a struct not have a member variable of this type?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by making the struct and/or the member variable function have `fileprivate` or `private` access control:

```swift
import _Differentiation

struct S {
    fileprivate var f: @differentiable(reverse) (Double, Double, Double) -> Double
}
```

or

```swift
import _Differentiation

fileprivate struct S {
    public var f: @differentiable(reverse) (Double, Double, Double) -> Double
}
```

Note in the second example that `f` can be `public` because `S` is restricted to at least `fileprivate`.

A work-around is to make `f` a function of another differentiable data structure, for example:

```swift
import _Differentiation

struct S {
    struct Tuple: Differentiable {
        var x: Double
        var y: Double
        @differentiable(reverse)
        init(x: Double, y: Double) {
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        }
    }
    var f: @differentiable(reverse) (Tuple) -> Double
}
```